# How to disable Teams Auto markdown using Incoming Webhook

Tags: curl, post, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to post some text to a Teams Channel.
Contents of my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE="MESSAGE TITLE"
COLOR="FF0000"
MESSAGE="This is my A_B_C message."
WEBHOOK_URL="https://teams/"

JSON="{\"title\": \"${TITLE}\", \"themeColor\": \"${COLOR}\", \"text\": \"${MESSAGE}\"}"

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "${JSON}" "${WEBHOOK_URL}"
```

Unfortunately, the message is shown as "This is my A*B*C message." (italic "B")

Is there any way to disable this Teams auto-markdown or to escape this properly?

I've already tried the following without success;

```
 MESSAGE_ESCAPED=$( echo ${MESSAGE} | sed 's/"/\"/g' | sed "s/'/\'/g" | sed "s/_/\\\_/g" )
```

Comment: Same problem here - any luck with that?

Comment: Nope... Had to change the execution of this task...

Answer (score 1):

Summary: switch to using an Adaptive Card. It's just a little extra boilerplate in the JSON and by using a RichTextBlock you can get predictable escaping.

Attempting to escape the text for markdown is never going to be reliable, or, at least, I wouldn't trust it for an automated system taking even semi-arbitrary data. When you use a simple text input to a webhook both markdown and a subset of HTML are interpreted. It's possible that escaping *all* punctuation characters might work but you'd never be sure (and the rules for escaping inside a monospaced section, that is, delimited by backticks, are different). Note that you have two levels of escaping: markdown escaping followed by JSON escaping. So `_` becomes `\_` becomes `\\_`. Escaping through all of that is not going to be reliable for arbitrary content and good luck building unit tests to make sure your escaping doesn't get broken in future.

Oh, and remember that sed needs backslashes to be escaped and the shell also needs them escaped and the shell's escaping rules are different for single-quoted and double-quoted text. I think this is why your tests weren't working, but my point still stands.

I strong recommend you avoid all of this by using a RichTextBlock in an adaptive card. There was a time when Teams webhooks didn't support Adaptive Cards but they do now.

There's an example of Adaptive Cards in [Send Adaptive Cards using an Incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook), but I'll work through it here adding some tips and tricks.

You send JSON that wraps a message with an attachment and make the Adaptive Card an attachment like this:

```
{
  "summary": "This text will go in the activity stream",
  "type":"message",
  "attachments":[
    {
      "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl":null,
      "content": { …the adaptive card goes here… }
    }
  ]
}
```

All of that is boilerplate apart from the summary field: if you omit the summary then the activity stream summary will just be "card". The curly braces in the content value are the same as the ones at the start and end of the card.

The adaptive card needs this boilerplate:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [ …a comma separated list of elements goes here… ]
}
```

You can make Adaptive Cards arbitrary complex, but for the purposes here there are two types of text sections: TextBlock and RichTextBlock. You can have as many of each of these as you want.

TextBlock carries text where markdown is interpreted (but not any HTML tags). You may use that for any constant parts of your message but avoid it for any place you want to carry variable content. A TextBlock can be as simple as:

```
{
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "text": "This is _markdown_.",
  "wrap": true
}
```

(The word "markdown" will be rendered in italics.)

There are other fields you can add to control the formatting to change the colour or the text size. See the [TextBlock documentation](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextBlock.html)

A RichTextBlock contains a list of TextRun elements. In each TextRun, the text field is just a JSON string that contains plain text. Nothing in there is interpreted as formatting. You just need to do normal JSON escaping of `\` and `"` (unless you have newlines). The formatting information is carried in other fields. Each TextRun can have different formatting and they'll be concatenated when rendered. So, the simplest RichTextBlock is:

```
{
  "type": "RichTextBlock",
  "inlines": [
    {
      "type": "TextRun",
      "text": "This is _plain text_."
    }
  ]
}
```

(The underscores will be rendered, nothing will be in italics.)

Other fields in the RichTextBlock control how the block as a whole is rendered (such as how much of a gap it should have from the previous element). Fields in the TextRun control how that piece of text is rendered. See the [RichTextBlock](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/RichTextBlock.html) and [TextRun](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextRun.html) documentation.

In RichTextBlocks, use `\n` in the text of a TextRun for a line break (equivalent of HTML `<br>`). Start a new RichTextBlock for a new paragraph (equivalent of HTML `<p>`). You could use `\n\n` to start a new paragraph but it's not as neat.

Assuming no newlines, you can do the JSON escaping with `sed -e 's/["\\]/\\&/g'`

Once you've got a basic Adaptive Card working you can go mad and add all sorts of fancy formatting.

I recommend using the [Adaptive Card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to prototype the of the Adaptive Card as it has a syntax checker (shows up as red highlighting in the scrollbar of the Card Payload Editor Pane, then mouseover the squiggly red line for the error).

Top tip: the most common problem is you've added or deleted a field or array element and forgotten to add or delete a comma.

Here's an example of the whole JSON query. Unfortunately, I've not been able to test the whole thing as I don't have access to a Teams webhook from home. If anyone finds a problem, then please edit this answer to correct the errors. I've used the Adaptive Card Designer for the card. It puts newlines and indentation in the JSON which I've left in place for readability. However, you this will work just as well squashed onto one line as in your original code. I've put in some complex markdown as an escaping challenge.

```
{
  "summary": "This text will go in the activity stream",
  "type":"message",
  "attachments":[
    {
      "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl":null,
      "content": {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is a **TextBlock**, `markdown` is _interpreted_ [link](http://www.example.com).\n- Item\n1. Item\n\n2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes with spaces \\ \\\\ \\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\ \n\n2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes with commas \\, \\\\, \\\\\\, \\\\\\\\, \\\\\\\\\\, \n\n2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes in text a\\a\\\\a\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\\\a",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "RichTextBlock",
            "inlines": [
              {
                "type": "TextRun",
                "text": "This is a **RichTextBlock**, `markdown` is not _interpreted_ [link](http://www.example.com).\n- Item\n1. Item\n"
              },
              {
                "type": "TextRun",
                "text": "Formatting is external to the text\n",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "color": "attention"
              },
              {
                "type": "TextRun",
                "text": "2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes with spaces \\ \\\\ \\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\ \n2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes with commas \\, \\\\, \\\\\\, \\\\\\\\, \\\\\\\\\\, \n2, 4, 6, 8, 10 backslashes in text a\\a\\\\a\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\\\a"
              }
            ]
          }
    ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's how the card part of it renders in the Adaptive Card Designer:

[image: Rendering of the example card]

Remember that if you're jumping between the whole webhook JSON payload and the Adaptive Card Designer then it's just the card (the value of the content field) that goes into the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your message before sending

```
MESSAGE=$(echo $MESSAGE | sed -e 's/_/\\\\_/g')
```